# Posenet on Raspi 4 w/ Coral USB Accelarator

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-coral

Has anyone managed to get posenet working on a RASPI4, using the Google Coral USB accelerator? If so, would you mind to share your github repo.

I'm looking to run this demo on a raspi.
[https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html][1]

I keep running into mixed issues, from segmentation fault to just random errors. Reading through all the blogs it seems it might be a performance issue of the USB slot?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the initial posenet for coral working?  https://github.com/google-coral/project-posenet   That could be a good starting point

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I don't. Don't even know where to start - I'm a beginner.